How to identify or to postMessage to a cross-origin <embed> element after redirection
I'm using a Chrome extension using MV3 to convert every frame to a shadow-root (to put inline their content), I need this because I cannot copy and paste iframe/embed/object frames from the browser to OneNote, Word, etc when I select all the page, I have to select the frame content one by one, but this consumes a lot of time. So I decided to convert them, which allows me to copy them all at once with one ctrl-c.
failed solutions:
postMessage
I solved iframes, and the conversion works very well, I used chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames to inject every frame and its parent, then I postMessage between them the content, and then I replace from the parent the subframe content because I can now identify the subframe by postMessage the frameid I got with getAllFrames. but I could not solve the <embed> frames:

 elements (HTMLEmbedElement) do not have contentWindow or
contentDocument so we cannot postmessage from the parent to its embed
frame. link

window.frames
So to get the content, I used this method: window.frames[] does include windows from <embed>, but it is not possible to tell whether an item in window.frames[] belongs to a specific <embed>, except in the same-origin case, where frames[i].frameElement can be compared with an <embed> element. link
But this method will not always work because ShadowDOM frames aren't exposed in the global window or frames, i mean window.frames do not include iframe/embed if they are inside a shadow roots. 1 2 3 4. And of course there is the cross-origin problem also.
frame.src
Another solution is to compare the frame src I get from getAllFrames (or window.location.href (sent from the embed to its parent)) with the frame.src I get from the frame's parent. This allows me to identify from the parent the correct embed frame, which I have to convert to a shadow-root. But this method fails if the embed frame is redirected to a new url, the standard says it clearly:

element's src attribute does not get updated if the content navigable
gets further navigated to other locations. link

getFrameId()
There is also runtime.getFrameId() which seems to solve all this problems, but Chrome do not want to implement it, Firefox implemented it, but I'm using chrome.
Not good solutions:
webrequest
One solution I can use is the webrequest api to intercept the redirections and save the old and new urls to identify the correct frame, but this means that I have to refresh the page, I want to avoid this, because I'm doing all this work to earn time when I copy/paste not to lose more time. Refreshing means I have to wait more time and I need to reopen any <details><summary>... etc
disable web security
I can run chrome with this flags --profile-directory="%Profile_name%"  --disable-site-isolation-trials --disable-web-security
this disable the web security so it eliminates the same-origin policy restrictions, so cross-origin problems are solved, but i cannot run all the time with this dangerous flags, and running every time a new chrome with this flags just for copy/paste means losing more time...

So now to identify the embed frame from its parent frame, I cannot use frame.src from the parent if it is redirected, and I cannot postmessage from the parent to its child embed frame like I did in iframes, and I cannot use window.frames for cross-origin frames or when the frame is inside a shadow-root. Is there another solution?
If you a need a test case, here is an example of a cross-origin  frame which will redirect to a new url
<div><embed src="https://iperasolutions.com" height="500" width="500"></div>


update for wOxxOm suggestion
This did not work for cross-origin frames, it works fine for same-origin frames.
there is an open bug about this:

cross origin iframes still can't be debugged via chrome.debugger
https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40752731

chrome.debugger.attach({ tabId: tabId }, "1.3", function () {
  // Enable auto-attach to subtargets
  chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId: tabId }, "Target.setAutoAttach", {
    autoAttach: true,
    waitForDebuggerOnStart: false,
    flatten: true,
  }, function () {
    chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId: tabId }, "DOMSnapshot.captureSnapshot", { computedStyles: [] }, function (snapshot) {
      console.log("snapshot", snapshot);
    });
});


update 2 for the second wOxxOm suggestion
DOM.getDocument
DOM.getDocument does not return cross-origin frames, and also this commands Page.getFrameTree and Page.getResourceTree
const getDocument = await chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId }, "DOM.getDocument", { depth: -1, pierce: true });
console.log("++++++++getDocument",getDocument);

const getFrameTree = await chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId }, "Page.getFrameTree", {});
console.log("++++++++getFrameTree: ", getFrameTree);
  
const getResourceTree = await chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId }, "Page.getResourceTree", {});
console.log("++++++++getResourceTree: ", getResourceTree);

when i run this in the protocol monitor in devtools, cross-origin frames are not returned too
{"command":"DOM.getDocument" ,"parameters":{"depth": -1, "pierce": true}}

if i disable web security by running chrome with --disable-site-isolation-trials --disable-web-security... all the above 3 commands returns cross-origin frames.
here is the full code:
const contextMap = new Map();
try {
  chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(handleDebuggerEvents);
  await chrome.debugger.attach({ tabId: tabId }, "1.3");
  // When you call Runtime.enable, it sends executionContextCreated events for all existing execution contexts. So you don’t have to worry about connecting late. https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-protocol/issues/72
  await chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId: tabId }, "Runtime.enable");
  console.log("contextMap",contextMap);    
  await injectScriptIntoAllFrames(tabId);
  await chrome.debugger.detach({ tabId: tabId });
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}


async function injectScriptIntoAllFrames(tabId) {
  const getDocument = await chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId }, "DOM.getDocument", { depth: -1, pierce: true });
  if (getDocument) {
    console.log("++++++++getDocument",getDocument);
    await traverseDOM(tabId, getDocument.root);
  }
}

async function traverseDOM(tabId, node) {
  if (node.frameId && (node.nodeName === 'IFRAME' || node.nodeName === 'EMBED' || node.nodeName === 'OBJECT')) {
    console.log("frameid",node.frameId);
    // const contextId = contextMap.get(node.frameId).id;
    // uniqueContextId: is An alternative way to specify the execution context to evaluate in. Compared to contextId that may be reused across processes, this is guaranteed to be system-unique, so it can be used to prevent accidental evaluation of the expression in context different than intended (e.g. as a result of navigation across process boundaries). This is mutually exclusive with `contextId`.EXPERiMENTAL
    const uniqueContextId = contextMap.get(node.frameId).uniqueId;
    console.log("=========uniqueContextId",uniqueContextId);
    await injectScriptIntoFrame(tabId, node.frameId, uniqueContextId);
  }

  if (node.children) {
    for (const child of node.children) {
      await traverseDOM(tabId, child);
    }
  }
}

async function injectScriptIntoFrame(tabId, frameId, uniqueContextId) {
  const evaluateResult = await chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId }, "Runtime.evaluate", {
    expression: `(async () => { 
      console.log("111",window.badr); 
      await new Promise((resolve) => {setTimeout(resolve, 3000);});
      return window.badr;
    })()`
    ,awaitPromise: true
    // ,contextId: contextId
    ,uniqueContextId: uniqueContextId
    // ,silent: true
  })
  if (evaluateResult) {
    if (evaluateResult.exceptionDetails) {
      console.error(`An error happened or Failed to inject script into frame ${frameId}:`, evaluateResult.exceptionDetails);
    } else {
      console.log("Runtime.evaluate result",evaluateResult.result.value);
    }
  }
}

function handleDebuggerEvents (source, method, params) {
  if (source.tabId !== tabId) return;

  if (method === "Runtime.executionContextsCleared") {
    contextMap.clear();
    console.log("Contexts cleared");
  }

  if (method === "Runtime.executionContextCreated") {
    const context = params.context;
    const frameId = context.auxData && context.auxData.frameId;
  
    // isDefault seems to be true only for main frame context,when i create a createIsolatedWorld or i inject a content script into the frame i see that isDefault is always false for those contexts. for main frame context the "name" seems to be always empty, and "type" is always  type: 'default', type in general may be: 'default'|'isolated'|'worker'
    if (frameId && context.auxData.isDefault) { 
      contextMap.set(frameId, context);
      console.log(`Context saved: ${frameId}`, contextMap.get(frameId));
    }
  } else if (method === "Runtime.executionContextDestroyed") {
    const executionContextId = params.executionContextId;
  
    for (const [frameId, context] of contextMap) {
      if (context.id === executionContextId) {
        contextMap.delete(frameId);
        console.log(`Context removed: ${frameId}`);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}


DOM.requestChildNodes
this also does not return cross-origin frames.
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
  const tabId = tabs[0].id;
  chrome.debugger.attach({ tabId }, "1.3", () => {
    chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId }, "DOM.getDocument", {}, (result) => {
      const rootNodeId = result.root.nodeId;
      requestChildNodes(tabId, rootNodeId);
    });
  });
});

function requestChildNodes(tabId, nodeId) {
  chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId },"DOM.requestChildNodes",{ nodeId },(result) => {
    console.log("Child nodes requested", result);
    chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId },"DOM.querySelectorAll",{ nodeId: nodeId, selector: '*' },(result) => {
      console.log("All nodes:", result);
    });
  });
}

chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener((source, method, params) => {
  if (method === "DOM.setChildNodes") {
    console.log("Child nodes set", params);
  }
});


a possible fix for chrome v124+ (not tested!)
i found this which seems similar and applicable to the above commands, it is about Page.getFrameTree

CDP method Page.getFrameTree with chrome.debugger API doesn't return cross-domain iframes
Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)
Page.getFrameTree only returns
local frames and it is working as expected. To attach to
out-of-process iframes (which are separate CDP targets and on which
you can call Page.getFrameTree again to get local frame trees), in the
latest Canary you can use CDP's auto-attach to automatically create
sessions for all OOPIFs
https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/5398119
source: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/333981074

so it seems it needs at least chrome v124+ and auto-attach, so no chance for win 7 and chrome v109 users like me :(

Maybe use chrome.debugger API and send DOMSnapshot.captureSnapshot?

@wOxxOm please see my update at the end of my question part. it worked fine for same-origin frames but cross-origin frames are empty. it seems a bug if i m not wrong see this issue : they say: cross origin iframes still can't be debugged via chrome.debugger https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40752731
it seems that it works fine when we use CDP from outside chrome extensions. is my above code correct or i m doing it incorrectly? any suggestion or other solution please?

Why don't you replace these elements to iframes?

@Kaiido which elements? i need to replace only one element: <embed>, and to replace it i need to identify it from its parent, but i cannot identify it because we cannot use postmessage with embed elements, and the frame.src also does not work when the embed is redirected to a new location.

I mean every time an  is appended in the DOM you replace it with an , so that there is no  at all in the DOM. Anyway they don't provide anything more than  (and their use should be discouraged these days).

@Kaiido ah yes, but this means i have to intercept all the sites i navigate using webrequest, or refresh the page to intercept the traffic when i need to copy/paste which consumes more time and a lot of resources. i hope to find a better solution

(I'm not a browser-extension specialist), can't you inject code that would do something akin to [...document.querySelectorAll("embed")].forEach(el => { const { src, width, height } = el; el.replaceWith(Object.assign(document.createElement("iframe"), { src, width, height }));});?

@Kaiido wow just wow, your solution left me speechless with an open mouth, this solved my problem, i love it. if you want to put your comment as an answer i will accept it. thank you very much for your time and code example.

With chrome.debugger you can use the same method devtools uses for those iframes i.e. DOM.getDocument, DOM.getFrameOwner, DOM.requestChildNodes. You can see it by enabling protocol monitor in devtools experiments.

@woxxom sorry for this late confirmation, but it took me all this time to learn and test what you told me. unfortunately none of those commands worked, cross-origin frames are not returned, please see my second update above called: update 2 for the second wOxxOm suggestion. Have you ever been able to use any of those commands successfully in a chrome extension with cross-origin frames? if yes then what i m doing wrong?

You need to use DOM.getFrameOwner. Use protocol monitor while inspecting an iframe in devtools. To make it faster you can type DOM. in the filter input in the toolbar.

@woxxom here is what happened, when i load the page for the first time DOM.getDocument, DOM.getFrameOwner and DOM.requestChildNodes are sent and the responses have no frame content, once i inspect the frame with the mouse none of those 3 commands is sent, and i receive only a DOM.setChildNodes event which contain the frame content. so those 3 commands are never sent to get setChildNodes event, so we cannot use them as you told me, it seems that it is the click who triggers setChildNodes!! any idea?

@woxxom i tested with this <div><embed src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP" height="100" width="100"></div>

I guess it's broken and I'm not that versed in chrome.debugger to find a workaround. You can run chrome with --remote-debugging-port=1234 command line and write an external script in node.js that uses CDP via this port and call it from your extension using chrome.runtime.connectNative.

@woxxom good. yes, using CDP from outside chrome extension should work, i used it in the past and had no problem at all, it is so powerful, but for our problem here i think external CDP will be too much cumbersome, so i think i have to stop here, it seems there is no 100% perfect solution for this (except external CDP), but anyway i learned a lot of things with your guidance which is more valuable than finding a solution, thank you very much for your time and patience.

One way would be to replace all the <embed> elements in the page with <iframe> ones, so that you can communicate with it as you wish.
Injecting something like below should do.
[...document.querySelectorAll("embed")].forEach((embed) => {
  const { src, width, height } = embed;
  const frame = Object.assign(document.createElement("iframe"), { src, width, height })
  embed.replaceWith(frame);
});

(This may cause some layout differences in the page).

this is a clever solution, convert it to an iframe and let the iframe re-fetch the src, this solves the redirection problem. simple and concise,  i spent a lot of time looking for a solution and never thought about this. thank you very very much

It will fail in case the embed navigated itself via location.href = newUrl which doesn't change src on the element. It will also reset JS/DOM state, although cross-origin iframes aren't usually stateful.

@wOxxOm for the location.href case it will also execute it in the iframe, so that's not an issue. The actual issue would more be in case the location or DOM was changed through the user's interaction, but since in this case the user is OP, I suppose it's ok.

There's no guarantee it will in case navigation happens in response to a message sent by the parent page only once after the embed was created. I don't think this is a frequent scenario but it's certainly possible.

The legitimate embedder can do it via window[0], the problem was that the extension can't know which window[xxx] corresponds to which embed. Another possibility is that the embed uses parent.postMessage and the parent replies with the new data used by the embed to navigate itself and the parent may have used a one-time listener when the embed was used the first time i.e. there will be no reaction when it's replaced by iframe.

@woxxom gosh, you're right. Completely forgot that was exposed there... As for the one time message handler... sure that's a possibility, that sounds quite unlikely though. Still, it seems you have a better solution? Please provide it!

Not necessarily a better solution, but chrome.debugger may be used to do what devtools does to extract the contents. It's complicated though and shows a warning on top of the browser when used.

@woxxom Still, since this seems to be for a personal extension that might be a good alternative. Also, this answer is a community wiki from the get go, please feell free to add any caveats from this solution as addendum to it.
